# How is -1 (integer) represented in big endian, 32 bit two's-complement bytes?

Tags: 32-bit, twos-complement

Sorry for the silly question, but I am having a bit of trouble sending a -1 over a network.

If 1 is....

**00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001**

..... should -1 not be....

**11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111**

..... which I am sending (**255 255 255 255**), but getting decimal value ....

**-1010842689**

.... at the other side.  Am I wrongly assuming the same 8 bit rules apply to 32 bit or something?

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**

It turns out that the output was being formatted in UTF-8, which doesn't allow the value 255 to be the first byte so was outputting something else (error code?).

Comment: Err? What protocol stack are you using to send -1?

Comment: I'm sending OSC commands over UDP.

Comment: The question is whether four 8 bit bytes of 0xFF in a 32bit, big endian, two's complement number represents -1 and if not, what does.

Comment: So sending -1 results in 0xC3BFC3BF on the other side. Are other numbers sent properly? And yes, 0xFFFFFFFF is -1 in twos complement.

Comment: The only other value I have sent is 1, 0x00000001 which is 1 on the other side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-1 is represented in 2s complement as all 1 bits.

I verified this in Java.  Java uses 32 bit 2s complement integers.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(-1));
        System.out.println(Integer.toHexString(-1010842689));
    }
}
```

The output:

```
ffffffff
c3bfc3bf
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I needed to know I wasn't losing it.

Answer (score 0):

That decimal value you are getting is equal to 0xFFFFFFFFC3BFC3BF, a 64-bit value.  If you're only sending 32-bits and you're reading sizeof( int ) bytes where sizeof( int ) is in fact 8 instead of 4, you might see something similar to this.

Comment: Oh ignore me.  It's far too late on a Friday afternoon to be answering things like this.  :)